# Is there a way to programmatically avoid EA trading under major FOREX news?

Tags: quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

May I know is there a way to programmatically detect major FOREX news and avoid trading in those time frame?

Answer (score 2):

You need Forexfactory news indicator, "FFCal", that reads data from the website and returns true/false depending on time in minutes before/after major/mid/minor news events. you can download it on fxfactory website, use is rather simple

`int result = (int)iCustom(Symbol(),0,"FFCal", (parameters),0,0);`

Comment: Not a safe way to use a per-QUOTE-called Custom Indicator automation, you may be well aware that *(cit.:)* "DISCLAIMER (Sept 17, 2016): Apparently some people have been getting the "Unable to process calendar" error. More info here >>> http://www.forexfactory.com/showthread.php?p=9144301#post9144301." and that the Downloader exhibits problems ( last update 2017/03 ).

Answer (score 1):

Oh sure, sir, it is!

Let me share an example of such a fully automated / scripted approach:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, may I know where do you get those red events? And what API you use to get them?